# How to change font size of longtable-lines without changing font size of caption?

Tags: tables, captions, koma-script, fontsize, longtable

I'd like to change the font size of all contents of a `longtable` to `footnotesize`. However the rest of the document *and also the caption (!)* shall be (stay) in normal size.
(`pdflatex` is used)

How can I do that?

- I tried to put the `\footnotesize`command outside the `longtable`-environment, but then the `caption` is also smaller.
- If I put the command in before the first line of the table, it is only executed for the first cell of the table.
- If I put it before `\endoffirsthead`, I get an error message during compiling.

EDIT: I don't want to be the whole document to be in `\footnotesize`, but **only** the content of the tables!

**Minimal example:**

```
\documentclass{scrbook}  
\usepackage{longtable, booktabs}  
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{ccc}
\caption{This is the caption of the table which shall be normal size!}\\ 
\toprule
aaaaaaa & bbbbbb & ccccccccc\\  
\midrule  
 a & b & c\\  
a & b & c\\
a & b & c\\  
a & b & c\\  
a & b & c\\  
a & b & c\\  
\bottomrule  
\end{longtable}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can modify the definition of `\LT@makecaption` in such a way that it uses `\normalsize`; since you are using `scrbook` one has to use *its* definition. I'll define a new environment that will make things easier.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}  
\usepackage{longtable, booktabs,etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{longtable*}[1]
  {%
    \renewcommand{\LT@makecaption}[3]{%
      \noalign{%
        \if@captionabove
          \vskip\belowcaptionskip
        \else
          \vskip\abovecaptionskip
        \fi
      }%
      \LT@mcol\LT@cols c{%
        \hbox to\z@{\normalsize\hss\parbox[t]\linewidth{%
            \@@makecaption{##1}{##2}{##3}%
            \endgraf
            \if@captionabove
              \vskip\abovecaptionskip
            \else
              \vskip\belowcaptionskip
            \fi
          }%
          \hss
        }%
      }%
    }%
   #1\begin{longtable}}
  {\end{longtable}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\hrule

\begin{longtable*}{\footnotesize}{ccc}
\caption{This is the caption of the table which shall be normal size!}\\ 
\toprule
aaaaaaa & bbbbbb & ccccccccc\\  
\midrule  
 a & b & c\\  
a & b & c\\
a & b & c\\  
a & b & c\\  
a & b & c\\  
a & b & c\\  
\bottomrule  
\end{longtable*}

\begin{longtable}{ccc}
\caption{This is the caption of the table which shall be normal size!}\\ 
\toprule
aaaaaaa & bbbbbb & ccccccccc\\  
\midrule  
 a & b & c\\  
a & b & c\\
a & b & c\\  
a & b & c\\  
a & b & c\\  
a & b & c\\  
\bottomrule  
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

The syntax of the `longtable*` environment is simple: it takes as argument the desired size of the table's body; the usual argument to `longtable` follows. I've left the two examples to show the difference.

Comment: thanks a lot! I've used this solution (and hope it will not have any unseen side effects)

Answer (score 11):

Since you are using a KOMA-Script document class you can simply use `\setkomafont` or `\addtokomafont` to set the size of the caption(s):

```
\documentclass[captions=tableheading]{scrbook}
\usepackage{longtable, booktabs}

\setkomafont{caption}{\normalsize}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\footnotesize
\begin{longtable}{ccc}
\caption{This is the caption of the table which shall be normal size!}\\
\toprule
aaaaaaa & bbbbbb & ccccccccc\\
\midrule
 a & b & c\\
a & b & c\\
a & b & c\\
a & b & c\\
a & b & c\\
a & b & c\\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

For other document classes one can include the `caption` package. Simply including is sufficient since `\normalsize` is the default caption size here (at least since version 3.1):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{longtable, booktabs}

\usepackage[tableposition=t]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\footnotesize
\begin{longtable}{ccc}
\caption{This is the caption of the table which shall be normal size!}\\
\toprule
aaaaaaa & bbbbbb & ccccccccc\\
\midrule
 a & b & c\\
a & b & c\\
a & b & c\\
a & b & c\\
a & b & c\\
a & b & c\\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

If someone is not using a KOMA-Script document class, but don't want to use the `caption` package either, one can give the `ltcaption` package a try which is part of the `caption` package bundle but patches the captioning stuff for longtables only:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{longtable, booktabs}

\usepackage{ltcaption}
% The ltcaption package supports \CaptionLabelFont & \CaptionTextFont
% introduced by the NTG document classes
\renewcommand\CaptionLabelFont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\CaptionTextFont{\normalsize}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\footnotesize
\begin{longtable}{ccc}
\caption{This is the caption of the table which shall be normal size!}\\
\toprule
aaaaaaa & bbbbbb & ccccccccc\\
\midrule
 a & b & c\\
a & b & c\\
a & b & c\\
a & b & c\\
a & b & c\\
a & b & c\\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do global change by keeping the following three lines in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[font=normalsize]{caption}     %% make caption in normal size
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{longtabu}{\footnotesize}{}{}   %% change all longtabu content to foot note size
```

as answered by Harish Kumar [here in this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164443/change-the-font-size-in-longtabu-table?rq=1)

Comment: This worked for me when replacing longtabu with longtable.

Answer (score 2):

You may try the new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}  

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}  

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {This is the caption of the table which shall be normal size!},
]{colspec={ccc},rows={font=\footnotesize}}
\toprule
aaaaaaa & bbbbbb & ccccccccc \\  
\midrule  
 a & b & c \\  
 a & b & c \\
 a & b & c \\  
 a & b & c \\  
 a & b & c \\  
 a & b & c \\  
\bottomrule  
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]