# Caption of longtable tables when using memoir

Tags: captions, memoir, longtable

It seems the `longtable` package provides its own captions totally separate from the ones provided by `memoir`. There is [a question on this site hinting at using the `caption` package for styling the `longtable` captions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11717/formating-captions-in-longtable-tables), however I am not sure the `caption` package should be used together with `memoir` since it provides its own captions which I don't want to have overloaded with other stuff. How would you recommend styling `longtable` captions when using the `memoir` captions for all other captions?

Comment: It it on my todo list, but it might be easier for you to simply use the `caption` package. AFAIR it does cover the longtable caption

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found on [another similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22730/how-to-change-font-size-of-longtable-lines-without-changing-font-size-of-caption) that there is a package known as `ltcaption` which can be used for changing the looks of captions for only `longtable`. It is not the perfect way since it will not be identical to the caption command of `memoir` I guess, but it is at least a step in the right direction.