# Change the font size in longtabu table

Tags: fontsize, longtable

I was searching here to find a way to change the font size from normal to \footnotesize for the longtabu tables. However, the answer in longtable question didn't work in my case. They made corrections for scriptbook style.

Basically, the question is the same: I want to change the font size of the main text in table without changing the caption size. Here is the example I tried to use what have been suggested: {\footnotesize ...
           }
But it makes the caption footnotesized.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report} 
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs, multicol, multirow}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Minimum Working Example}
Composition of samples
{\footnotesize
\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth{X[l3.0] X[c] X[c] X[c] X[c] X[c]} 
\caption{Composition of samples} \\ 
\toprule
\textbf{Component} & \textbf{Text1} & \textbf{Text2} & \textbf{Text3} & \textbf{Text4} & \textbf{Text5} \\
\midrule
H$_2$   & 3.94  & 3.81  & 4.03  & 3.88  & 4.01 \\
O$_2$   & 0.38  & 0.10  & 0.30  & 0.91  & 0.99 \\
C$_1$    & 11.98 & 11.30 & 10.98 & 11.94 & 11.09 \\
C$_2$    & 0.44  & 0.39  & 0.43  & 0.91  & 0.33 \\
N$_2$   & 3.94  & 3.81  & 4.03  & 3.88  & 4.01 \\
S$_2$    & 0.81  & 0.81  & 0.81  & 0.11  & 0.83 \\
C$_3$    & 9.19  & 9.01  & 9.10  & 9.84  & 9.18 \\
H$_2$   & 3.94  & 3.81  & 4.03  & 3.88  & 4.01 \\
O$_2$   & 0.38  & 0.10  & 0.30  & 0.91  & 0.99 \\
C$_1$    & 11.98 & 11.30 & 10.98 & 11.94 & 11.09 \\
C$_2$    & 0.44  & 0.39  & 0.43  & 0.91  & 0.33 \\
N$_2$   & 3.94  & 3.81  & 4.03  & 3.88  & 4.01 \\
S$_2$    & 0.81  & 0.81  & 0.81  & 0.11  & 0.83 \\
C$_3$    & 9.19  & 9.01  & 9.10  & 9.84  & 9.18 \\
H$_2$   & 3.94  & 3.81  & 4.03  & 3.88  & 4.01 \\
O$_2$   & 0.38  & 0.10  & 0.30  & 0.91  & 0.99 \\
C$_1$    & 11.98 & 11.30 & 10.98 & 11.94 & 11.09 \\
C$_2$    & 0.44  & 0.39  & 0.43  & 0.91  & 0.33 \\
N$_2$   & 3.94  & 3.81  & 4.03  & 3.88  & 4.01 \\
S$_2$    & 0.81  & 0.81  & 0.81  & 0.11  & 0.83 \\
C$_3$    & 9.19  & 9.01  & 9.10  & 9.84  & 9.18 \\
H$_2$   & 3.94  & 3.81  & 4.03  & 3.88  & 4.01 \\
O$_2$   & 0.38  & 0.10  & 0.30  & 0.91  & 0.99 \\
C$_1$    & 11.98 & 11.30 & 10.98 & 11.94 & 11.09 \\
C$_2$    & 0.44  & 0.39  & 0.43  & 0.91  & 0.33 \\
N$_2$   & 3.94  & 3.81  & 4.03  & 3.88  & 4.01 \\
S$_2$    & 0.81  & 0.81  & 0.81  & 0.11  & 0.83 \\
C$_3$    & 9.19  & 9.01  & 9.10  & 9.84  & 9.18 \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtabu}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please reduce your MWE to a minimum. Is the csm.sty having any effect on your desired result? Remove all packages you don't need for this question. `tabu` to `multirow` should already be enough here. Do you want all tabus or all longtabus or just this one to be scriptsize?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've cut your code down a bit for demonstration purposes, to make it a bit more minimal. But one way to do this is to specify the font size for each entry through the setup of the `longtabu` environment. For example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

Composition of samples

\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth{>{\footnotesize}X[l3.0] *{5}{>{\footnotesize}X[c]}}
\caption{Composition of samples} \\
\toprule
\textbf{Component} & \textbf{Text1} & \textbf{Text2} & \textbf{Text3} & \textbf{Text4} & \textbf{Text5} \\
\midrule
H$_2$   & 3.94  & 3.81  & 4.03  & 3.88  & 4.01 \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

Because the declaration `\footnotesize` affects only the relevant column, it does not affect the caption. However, you do need to specify it for each column. If you have several consecutive columns with the same definition, however, you can combine those using the `*{<number>}{<column specification>}` syntax as I've done for 5 of the 6 columns in this case.

This produces:

[image: Footnotesize text in <code>longtabu</code> with regular sized caption]

Answer (score 3):

You can take help from `caption` package to keep captions in normal font size. To ease the conversion of `\footnotesize` inside all `longtabu` environments, you can employ `\AtBeginDocument` macro from `etoolbox` package. This means, you don't have to type `\footnotesize` inside all `longtabu` environments. The essence is, add the following in your preamble:

```
\usepackage[font=normalsize]{caption}     %% make caption in normal size
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{longtabu}{\footnotesize}{}{}   %% change all longtabu content to foot note size
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs, multicol, multirow}
\usepackage[font=normalsize]{caption}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{longtabu}{\footnotesize}{}{}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Minimum Working Example}
Composition of samples

\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth{X[l3.0] X[c] X[c] X[c] X[c] X[c]}
\caption{Composition of samples} \\
\toprule
\textbf{Component} & \textbf{Text1} & \textbf{Text2} & \textbf{Text3} & \textbf{Text4} & \textbf{Text5} \\
\midrule
H$_2$   & 3.94  & 3.81  & 4.03  & 3.88  & 4.01 \\
O$_2$   & 0.38  & 0.10  & 0.30  & 0.91  & 0.99 \\
C$_1$    & 11.98 & 11.30 & 10.98 & 11.94 & 11.09 \\
C$_2$    & 0.44  & 0.39  & 0.43  & 0.91  & 0.33 \\
N$_2$   & 3.94  & 3.81  & 4.03  & 3.88  & 4.01 \\
S$_2$    & 0.81  & 0.81  & 0.81  & 0.11  & 0.83 \\
C$_3$    & 9.19  & 9.01  & 9.10  & 9.84  & 9.18 \\
H$_2$   & 3.94  & 3.81  & 4.03  & 3.88  & 4.01 \\
O$_2$   & 0.38  & 0.10  & 0.30  & 0.91  & 0.99 \\
C$_1$    & 11.98 & 11.30 & 10.98 & 11.94 & 11.09 \\
C$_2$    & 0.44  & 0.39  & 0.43  & 0.91  & 0.33 \\
N$_2$   & 3.94  & 3.81  & 4.03  & 3.88  & 4.01 \\
S$_2$    & 0.81  & 0.81  & 0.81  & 0.11  & 0.83 \\
C$_3$    & 9.19  & 9.01  & 9.10  & 9.84  & 9.18 \\
H$_2$   & 3.94  & 3.81  & 4.03  & 3.88  & 4.01 \\
O$_2$   & 0.38  & 0.10  & 0.30  & 0.91  & 0.99 \\
C$_1$    & 11.98 & 11.30 & 10.98 & 11.94 & 11.09 \\
C$_2$    & 0.44  & 0.39  & 0.43  & 0.91  & 0.33 \\
N$_2$   & 3.94  & 3.81  & 4.03  & 3.88  & 4.01 \\
S$_2$    & 0.81  & 0.81  & 0.81  & 0.11  & 0.83 \\
C$_3$    & 9.19  & 9.01  & 9.10  & 9.84  & 9.18 \\
H$_2$   & 3.94  & 3.81  & 4.03  & 3.88  & 4.01 \\
O$_2$   & 0.38  & 0.10  & 0.30  & 0.91  & 0.99 \\
C$_1$    & 11.98 & 11.30 & 10.98 & 11.94 & 11.09 \\
C$_2$    & 0.44  & 0.39  & 0.43  & 0.91  & 0.33 \\
N$_2$   & 3.94  & 3.81  & 4.03  & 3.88  & 4.01 \\
S$_2$    & 0.81  & 0.81  & 0.81  & 0.11  & 0.83 \\
C$_3$    & 9.19  & 9.01  & 9.10  & 9.84  & 9.18 \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

[image]