# Change longtable's font size without changing the caption

Tags: captions, memoir, fontsize, longtable

I'm trying to put quite a long table in my thesis. To save some space I want to reduce the row height, the column separator and use a smaller font size in the table. The problem with the following code is that it affects the caption too.

```
\begingroup
   \tiny \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8} \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
   \begin{longtable}[c]{r*{13}{c}}
      ...
   \caption{lipsum}
   \end{longtable}
\endgroup
```

I was not able to use egreg's answer in [How to change font size of longtable-lines without changing font size of caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22730/how-to-change-font-size-of-longtable-lines-without-changing-font-size-of-caption) Probably because I use a different document class. I use a custom (who would have figured?) thesis class of my department which is based on `memoir`. It gives me

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\LT@makecaption ...#3->\noalign {\if@captionabove 
                                                  \vskip \belowcaptionskip \...
l.145           \caption{Caption}
```

MWE (without the code from egreg's answer resulting in the above undefined control sequence):

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{longtable, booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \begingroup
        \tiny \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8} \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
        \begin{longtable}[c]{r*{13}{c}}
            \toprule
            \multirow{2}{*}{\#} & \# global & global & global & \# local & local & local & $p_1$ & $p_2$ & $p_3$ & $e$ & $|p_1-e|$ & $|p_2-e|$ & $|p_3-e|$ \\
            & optima & reach 1 & reach 2 & optima & reach 1 & reach 2 & (\%) & (\%) & (\%) & (\%) & (\%) & (\%) & (\%) \\
            \midrule
            1 & 33 & 3001 & 38927 & 23 & 85 & 4882 & 59 & 97 & 92 & 78 & 19 & 19 & 14 \\
            2 & 29 & 3179 & 49835 & 11 & 144 & 5407 & 73 & 95 & 92 & 70 & 2 & 25 & 22 \\
            3 & 4 & 3059 & 14552 & 24 & 425 & 14828 & 14 & 87 & 66 & 61 & 47 & 26 & 4 \\
            4 & 6 & 3919 & 23954 & 20 & 47 & 10387 & 23 & 98 & 84 & 77 & 54 & 21 & 6 \\
            5 & 8 & 3454 & 17387 & 21 & 88 & 10452 & 28 & 97 & 77 & 66 & 39 & 30 & 11 \\
            6 & 36 & 4415 & 53055 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
            7 & 2 & 2149 & 6978 & 40 & 937 & 33227 & 5 & 69 & 37 & 30 & 25 & 39 & 7 \\
            8 & 7 & 3485 & 14971 & 42 & 256 & 21247 & 14 & 92 & 65 & 61 & 47 & 31 & 4 \\
            9 & 1 & 2191 & 4980 & 30 & 686 & 27566 & 3 & 75 & 37 & 46 & 43 & 29 & 9 \\
            10 & 9 & 4476 & 20569 & 2 & 265 & 1902 & 82 & 94 & 93 & 83 & 2 & 11 & 10 \\
            11 & 5 & 2600 & 13109 & 25 & 667 & 18666 & 17 & 79 & 56 & 48 & 32 & 31 & 8 \\
            12 & 19 & 5146 & 39396 & 1 & 0 & 6 & 95 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 5 & 0 & 0 \\
            13 & 8 & 3994 & 29304 & 12 & 51 & 9422 & 40 & 98 & 87 & 88 & 48 & 11 & 1 \\
            14 & 4 & 4255 & 13786 & 34 & 124 & 9081 & 11 & 96 & 80 & 68 & 57 & 29 & 12 \\
            15 & 57 & 2874 & 43973 & 2 & 0 & 133 & 97 & 100 & 100 & 98 & 1 & 2 & 2 \\
            16 & 5 & 2788 & 12762 & 12 & 1130 & 15705 & 29 & 71 & 57 & 45 & 16 & 26 & 12 \\
            17 & 1 & 1695 & 3256 & 47 & 1542 & 23186 & 2 & 52 & 28 & 21 & 19 & 31 & 7 \\
            18 & 11 & 3000 & 22911 & 7 & 942 & 5286 & 61 & 76 & 79 & 63 & 2 & 13 & 16 \\
            19 & 4 & 1931 & 11220 & 46 & 681 & 27978 & 8 & 73 & 43 & 32 & 24 & 41 & 11 \\
            20 & 2 & 2313 & 9496 & 16 & 1025 & 16374 & 11 & 69 & 50 & 44 & 33 & 25 & 6 \\
            21 & 6 & 3001 & 17725 & 11 & 849 & 10174 & 35 & 78 & 70 & 59 & 24 & 19 & 11 \\
            22 & 11 & 3110 & 26569 & 26 & 176 & 14097 & 30 & 94 & 77 & 62 & 32 & 32 & 15 \\
            23 & 3 & 1544 & 8928 & 18 & 1660 & 18922 & 14 & 48 & 38 & 28 & 13 & 20 & 11 \\
            24 & 2 & 2493 & 10244 & 11 & 930 & 13499 & 15 & 73 & 56 & 61 & 46 & 12 & 6 \\
            25 & 4 & 4507 & 16480 & 3 & 111 & 3089 & 57 & 98 & 92 & 91 & 34 & 6 & 1 \\
            26 & 5 & 3887 & 19543 & 12 & 313 & 5750 & 29 & 92 & 85 & 78 & 48 & 15 & 7 \\
            27 & 7 & 3807 & 15196 & 18 & 346 & 12575 & 28 & 91 & 73 & 66 & 38 & 26 & 8 \\
            28 & 9 & 3475 & 24734 & 18 & 356 & 7398 & 33 & 90 & 83 & 59 & 26 & 31 & 24 \\
            29 & 14 & 4498 & 34149 & 4 & 2 & 1106 & 78 & 100 & 99 & 99 & 21 & 1 & 0 \\
            30 & 2 & 3553 & 9495 & 28 & 855 & 12517 & 7 & 80 & 63 & 56 & 49 & 25 & 8 \\
            31 & 2 & 2420 & 6294 & 33 & 874 & 13472 & 6 & 73 & 48 & 39 & 33 & 34 & 9 \\
            32 & 4 & 4560 & 12669 & 12 & 114 & 6343 & 25 & 97 & 84 & 87 & 62 & 10 & 3 \\
            33 & 8 & 3470 & 21527 & 84 & 146 & 27083 & 9 & 94 & 67 & 57 & 48 & 37 & 10 \\
            34 & 6 & 4432 & 18421 & 5 & 281 & 3504 & 55 & 94 & 90 & 81 & 26 & 13 & 9 \\
            35 & 5 & 3416 & 17312 & 23 & 184 & 16463 & 18 & 94 & 70 & 68 & 50 & 27 & 3 \\
            36 & 1 & 2031 & 4433 & 24 & 1224 & 18491 & 4 & 62 & 36 & 45 & 41 & 17 & 8 \\
            37 & 30 & 4804 & 56228 & 2 & 0 & 290 & 94 & 100 & 100 & 97 & 4 & 3 & 2 \\
            38 & 4 & 3260 & 17592 & 6 & 762 & 5336 & 40 & 81 & 79 & 62 & 22 & 19 & 17 \\
            39 & 2 & 3041 & 10377 & 20 & 609 & 15052 & 9 & 83 & 60 & 57 & 48 & 26 & 3 \\
            40 & 2 & 1749 & 6278 & 39 & 1064 & 28640 & 5 & 61 & 33 & 57 & 53 & 4 & 24 \\
            41 & 12 & 4085 & 26084 & 6 & 204 & 4524 & 67 & 95 & 90 & 81 & 14 & 14 & 9 \\
            42 & 3 & 2614 & 10498 & 24 & 919 & 11723 & 11 & 74 & 59 & 46 & 35 & 28 & 13 \\
            43 & 25 & 3453 & 41419 & 13 & 51 & 3935 & 66 & 98 & 94 & 83 & 17 & 15 & 11 \\
            44 & 6 & 3502 & 25113 & 10 & 191 & 7150 & 38 & 95 & 85 & 72 & 35 & 22 & 13 \\
            45 & 4 & 3099 & 12912 & 19 & 425 & 14178 & 17 & 87 & 65 & 61 & 44 & 26 & 4 \\
            46 & 8 & 4107 & 19800 & 18 & 111 & 6258 & 31 & 97 & 87 & 74 & 43 & 23 & 13 \\
            47 & 6 & 3037 & 21570 & 18 & 727 & 19776 & 25 & 80 & 65 & 52 & 27 & 28 & 13 \\
            48 & 14 & 2995 & 37882 & 10 & 732 & 8220 & 58 & 80 & 81 & 65 & 7 & 15 & 16 \\
            49 & 14 & 3035 & 30844 & 21 & 212 & 9652 & 40 & 93 & 83 & 61 & 21 & 32 & 22 \\
            50 & 8 & 4682 & 19595 & 11 & 75 & 3011 & 42 & 98 & 93 & 85 & 43 & 13 & 8 \\
            51 & 5 & 4705 & 15508 & 14 & 72 & 5187 & 26 & 98 & 89 & 82 & 56 & 16 & 7 \\
            52 & 5 & 2689 & 16291 & 21 & 653 & 15165 & 19 & 80 & 63 & 49 & 29 & 31 & 15 \\
            53 & 9 & 4293 & 24187 & 6 & 64 & 4828 & 60 & 98 & 91 & 90 & 30 & 9 & 2 \\
            54 & 2 & 2984 & 8316 & 24 & 457 & 20057 & 8 & 86 & 53 & 55 & 48 & 31 & 2 \\
            55 & 23 & 4592 & 36227 & 1 & 0 & 169 & 96 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 4 & 0 & 0 \\
            56 & 2 & 3017 & 7494 & 23 & 808 & 11079 & 8 & 78 & 58 & 58 & 50 & 21 & 1 \\
            57 & 14 & 4036 & 24331 & 23 & 7 & 6778 & 38 & 99 & 89 & 85 & 47 & 15 & 4 \\
            58 & 9 & 3886 & 29559 & 7 & 224 & 4243 & 56 & 94 & 91 & 72 & 16 & 23 & 19 \\
            59 & 3 & 3312 & 12149 & 13 & 699 & 13556 & 19 & 82 & 64 & 60 & 41 & 23 & 5 \\
            60 & 20 & 3865 & 26047 & 4 & 22 & 1164 & 83 & 99 & 97 & 92 & 9 & 7 & 5 \\
            61 & 4 & 3807 & 10305 & 11 & 223 & 7531 & 27 & 94 & 76 & 72 & 45 & 23 & 4 \\
            62 & 4 & 3375 & 9418 & 44 & 156 & 14695 & 8 & 94 & 63 & 55 & 47 & 39 & 8 \\
            63 & 18 & 3779 & 36773 & 6 & 58 & 2133 & 75 & 98 & 96 & 89 & 14 & 9 & 7 \\
            64 & 26 & 4228 & 39503 & 7 & 0 & 829 & 79 & 100 & 99 & 96 & 17 & 4 & 3 \\
            65 & 4 & 2889 & 11938 & 41 & 475 & 18420 & 9 & 85 & 58 & 42 & 34 & 42 & 16 \\
            66 & 4 & 2963 & 12567 & 28 & 337 & 15446 & 13 & 89 & 63 & 47 & 34 & 42 & 16 \\
            67 & 13 & 5727 & 42627 & 4 & 0 & 372 & 76 & 100 & 100 & 96 & 19 & 4 & 4 \\
            68 & 6 & 2871 & 16348 & 10 & 738 & 7918 & 38 & 79 & 73 & 55 & 17 & 25 & 18 \\
            69 & 2 & 1868 & 7427 & 35 & 1056 & 26696 & 5 & 63 & 37 & 33 & 27 & 30 & 4 \\
            70 & 17 & 3604 & 29458 & 18 & 42 & 6866 & 49 & 98 & 89 & 69 & 21 & 29 & 20 \\
            71 & 3 & 5095 & 11407 & 7 & 16 & 3606 & 30 & 100 & 91 & 86 & 56 & 13 & 4 \\
            72 & 10 & 3660 & 25456 & 29 & 164 & 7578 & 26 & 95 & 86 & 71 & 45 & 24 & 14 \\
            73 & 1 & 1286 & 2800 & 39 & 1509 & 31159 & 3 & 45 & 21 & 17 & 15 & 28 & 4 \\
            74 & 31 & 3678 & 38338 & 2 & 6 & 966 & 94 & 100 & 99 & 94 & 0 & 6 & 5 \\
            75 & 37 & 3475 & 35754 & 1 & 0 & 38 & 97 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\
            76 & 4 & 3633 & 13414 & 15 & 281 & 9752 & 21 & 92 & 75 & 73 & 52 & 20 & 2 \\
            77 & 4 & 4027 & 14324 & 10 & 528 & 7550 & 29 & 88 & 78 & 63 & 35 & 25 & 15 \\
            78 & 6 & 4050 & 18021 & 13 & 59 & 7520 & 32 & 98 & 85 & 72 & 40 & 26 & 13 \\
            79 & 4 & 2684 & 10807 & 23 & 485 & 12193 & 15 & 84 & 61 & 44 & 30 & 40 & 17 \\
            80 & 24 & 3977 & 44696 & 12 & 13 & 4172 & 67 & 99 & 95 & 89 & 23 & 10 & 6 \\
            81 & 2 & 1126 & 5397 & 28 & 2161 & 24036 & 7 & 34 & 25 & 21 & 14 & 13 & 4 \\
            82 & 25 & 3516 & 27515 & 11 & 31 & 1966 & 69 & 99 & 96 & 85 & 16 & 14 & 11 \\
            83 & 10 & 4834 & 41025 & 5 & 19 & 3540 & 67 & 100 & 96 & 90 & 23 & 10 & 7 \\
            84 & 29 & 5083 & 57971 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
            85 & 28 & 4293 & 42918 & 1 & 0 & 181 & 97 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\
            86 & 6 & 4224 & 16577 & 7 & 111 & 4214 & 46 & 97 & 89 & 76 & 29 & 22 & 13 \\
            87 & 11 & 3689 & 19672 & 25 & 102 & 10972 & 31 & 97 & 79 & 70 & 39 & 27 & 10 \\
            88 & 1 & 1496 & 3735 & 28 & 1647 & 29735 & 3 & 47 & 25 & 30 & 27 & 17 & 5 \\
            89 & 5 & 4083 & 17870 & 7 & 114 & 4593 & 42 & 97 & 89 & 85 & 43 & 12 & 4 \\
            90 & 20 & 3711 & 32478 & 14 & 40 & 3570 & 59 & 99 & 94 & 87 & 28 & 12 & 7 \\
            91 & 6 & 3905 & 20334 & 21 & 114 & 13450 & 22 & 97 & 78 & 71 & 49 & 26 & 7 \\
            92 & 2 & 2024 & 7164 & 45 & 1157 & 26033 & 4 & 63 & 38 & 28 & 24 & 35 & 10 \\
            93 & 6 & 4331 & 19434 & 24 & 54 & 8137 & 20 & 98 & 85 & 81 & 61 & 18 & 5 \\
            94 & 4 & 3617 & 19607 & 11 & 376 & 9633 & 27 & 90 & 78 & 68 & 41 & 22 & 10 \\
            95 & 5 & 3955 & 18959 & 13 & 128 & 9825 & 28 & 97 & 81 & 80 & 52 & 16 & 1 \\
            96 & 20 & 4098 & 43062 & 7 & 23 & 3181 & 74 & 99 & 96 & 90 & 16 & 9 & 6 \\
            97 & 1 & 1707 & 4099 & 25 & 1279 & 18039 & 4 & 57 & 33 & 34 & 30 & 22 & 2 \\
            98 & 25 & 3694 & 37010 & 11 & 36 & 2635 & 69 & 99 & 96 & 83 & 13 & 16 & 13 \\
            99 & 2 & 2012 & 7367 & 23 & 1217 & 21431 & 8 & 62 & 40 & 32 & 24 & 30 & 8 \\
            100 & 5 & 3745 & 16101 & 7 & 356 & 5564 & 42 & 91 & 83 & 72 & 31 & 19 & 10 \\ 
            \bottomrule
            \caption{Caption}
        \end{longtable}
    \endgroup
\end{document}
```

So my question is: How can I make local changes (font size, row height, column width) to a `longtable` without affecting anything else in the document including the `longtable` captions?

Answer (score 6):

I would also suggest to use `caption.sty`.  I suggest you put your caption above your `longtable` and use the facilities provided by `caption.sty` to customize it.  This means you can use `\caption` and not `\captionof`.  I would also drop `multirow` and use `makecell` (see below):

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{longtable, booktabs, multirow, caption, lmodern, makecell}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\captionsetup[longtable]{%
  labelfont={large,bf,it} ,
  textfont={large,sc}     ,
  position=top            ,
  belowskip=0pt           ,
  aboveskip=3pt
}

\begin{document}
  \begingroup
  \tiny \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8} \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
  \begin{longtable}[c]{@{}r*{13}{r}@{}}
    \caption{Caption of my longtable}\\
    \toprule
    \# & \makecell[tl]{\# global\\ optima} & \makecell[tl]{global\\ reach 1}
       & \makecell[tl]{global\\ reach 2}   & \makecell[tl]{\# local\\ optima}
       & \makecell[tl]{local\\ reach 1}    & \makecell[tl]{local\\ reach 2}
       & \makecell[tl]{$p_1$}              & \makecell[tl]{$p_2$} 
       & \makecell[tl]{$p_3$}              & \makecell[tl]{$e$}
       & \makecell[tl]{$|p_1-e|$}          & \makecell[tl]{$|p_2-e|$}
       & \makecell[tl]{$|p_3-e|$} \\
       & & & & & & & (\%) & (\%) & (\%) & (\%) & (\%) & (\%) & (\%) \\
    \midrule
    1   & 33 & 3001 & 38927 & 23 & 85 & 4882 & 59 & 97 & 92 & 78 & 19 & 19 & 14 \\
    2   & 29 & 3179 & 49835 & 11 & 144 & 5407 & 73 & 95 & 92 & 70 & 2 & 25 & 22 \\
    3   & 4  & 3059 & 14552 & 24 & 425 & 14828 & 14 & 87 & 66 & 61 & 47 & 26 & 4 \\
    4   & 6  & 3919 & 23954 & 20 & 47 & 10387 & 23 & 98 & 84 & 77 & 54 & 21 & 6 \\
    5   & 8  & 3454 & 17387 & 21 & 88 & 10452 & 28 & 97 & 77 & 66 & 39 & 30 & 11 \\
    6   & 36 & 4415 & 53055 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    7   & 2 & 2149 & 6978 & 40 & 937 & 33227 & 5 & 69 & 37 & 30 & 25 & 39 & 7 \\
    8   & 7 & 3485 & 14971 & 42 & 256 & 21247 & 14 & 92 & 65 & 61 & 47 & 31 & 4 \\
    9   & 1 & 2191 & 4980 & 30 & 686 & 27566 & 3 & 75 & 37 & 46 & 43 & 29 & 9 \\
    10  & 9 & 4476 & 20569 & 2 & 265 & 1902 & 82 & 94 & 93 & 83 & 2 & 11 & 10 \\
    11  & 5 & 2600 & 13109 & 25 & 667 & 18666 & 17 & 79 & 56 & 48 & 32 & 31 & 8 \\
    12  & 19 & 5146 & 39396 & 1 & 0 & 6 & 95 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 5 & 0 & 0 \\
    13  & 8 & 3994 & 29304 & 12 & 51 & 9422 & 40 & 98 & 87 & 88 & 48 & 11 & 1 \\
    14  & 4 & 4255 & 13786 & 34 & 124 & 9081 & 11 & 96 & 80 & 68 & 57 & 29 & 12 \\
    15  & 57 & 2874 & 43973 & 2 & 0 & 133 & 97 & 100 & 100 & 98 & 1 & 2 & 2 \\
    16  & 5 & 2788 & 12762 & 12 & 1130 & 15705 & 29 & 71 & 57 & 45 & 16 & 26 & 12 \\
    17  & 1 & 1695 & 3256 & 47 & 1542 & 23186 & 2 & 52 & 28 & 21 & 19 & 31 & 7 \\
    18  & 11 & 3000 & 22911 & 7 & 942 & 5286 & 61 & 76 & 79 & 63 & 2 & 13 & 16 \\
    19  & 4 & 1931 & 11220 & 46 & 681 & 27978 & 8 & 73 & 43 & 32 & 24 & 41 & 11 \\
    20  & 2 & 2313 & 9496 & 16 & 1025 & 16374 & 11 & 69 & 50 & 44 & 33 & 25 & 6 \\
    21  & 6 & 3001 & 17725 & 11 & 849 & 10174 & 35 & 78 & 70 & 59 & 24 & 19 & 11 \\
    22  & 11 & 3110 & 26569 & 26 & 176 & 14097 & 30 & 94 & 77 & 62 & 32 & 32 & 15 \\
    23  & 3 & 1544 & 8928 & 18 & 1660 & 18922 & 14 & 48 & 38 & 28 & 13 & 20 & 11 \\
    24  & 2 & 2493 & 10244 & 11 & 930 & 13499 & 15 & 73 & 56 & 61 & 46 & 12 & 6 \\
    25  & 4 & 4507 & 16480 & 3 & 111 & 3089 & 57 & 98 & 92 & 91 & 34 & 6 & 1 \\
    26  & 5 & 3887 & 19543 & 12 & 313 & 5750 & 29 & 92 & 85 & 78 & 48 & 15 & 7 \\
    27  & 7 & 3807 & 15196 & 18 & 346 & 12575 & 28 & 91 & 73 & 66 & 38 & 26 & 8 \\
    28  & 9 & 3475 & 24734 & 18 & 356 & 7398 & 33 & 90 & 83 & 59 & 26 & 31 & 24 \\
    29  & 14 & 4498 & 34149 & 4 & 2 & 1106 & 78 & 100 & 99 & 99 & 21 & 1 & 0 \\
    30  & 2 & 3553 & 9495 & 28 & 855 & 12517 & 7 & 80 & 63 & 56 & 49 & 25 & 8 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{longtable}
  \endgroup
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 3):

You could just create the caption after setting the table:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{longtable, booktabs, multirow, caption}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
  \begingroup
  \tiny \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8} \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
  \begin{longtable}[c]{r*{13}{c}}
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}{*}{\#} & \# global & global & global & \# local & local & local & $p_1$ & $p_2$ & $p_3$ & $e$ & $|p_1-e|$ & $|p_2-e|$ & $|p_3-e|$ \\
    & optima & reach 1 & reach 2 & optima & reach 1 & reach 2 & (\%) & (\%) & (\%) & (\%) & (\%) & (\%) & (\%) \\
    \midrule
    1 & 33 & 3001 & 38927 & 23 & 85 & 4882 & 59 & 97 & 92 & 78 & 19 & 19 & 14 \\
    2 & 29 & 3179 & 49835 & 11 & 144 & 5407 & 73 & 95 & 92 & 70 & 2 & 25 & 22 \\
    3 & 4 & 3059 & 14552 & 24 & 425 & 14828 & 14 & 87 & 66 & 61 & 47 & 26 & 4 \\
    4 & 6 & 3919 & 23954 & 20 & 47 & 10387 & 23 & 98 & 84 & 77 & 54 & 21 & 6 \\
    5 & 8 & 3454 & 17387 & 21 & 88 & 10452 & 28 & 97 & 77 & 66 & 39 & 30 & 11 \\
    6 & 36 & 4415 & 53055 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    7 & 2 & 2149 & 6978 & 40 & 937 & 33227 & 5 & 69 & 37 & 30 & 25 & 39 & 7 \\
    8 & 7 & 3485 & 14971 & 42 & 256 & 21247 & 14 & 92 & 65 & 61 & 47 & 31 & 4 \\
    9 & 1 & 2191 & 4980 & 30 & 686 & 27566 & 3 & 75 & 37 & 46 & 43 & 29 & 9 \\
    10 & 9 & 4476 & 20569 & 2 & 265 & 1902 & 82 & 94 & 93 & 83 & 2 & 11 & 10 \\
    11 & 5 & 2600 & 13109 & 25 & 667 & 18666 & 17 & 79 & 56 & 48 & 32 & 31 & 8 \\
    12 & 19 & 5146 & 39396 & 1 & 0 & 6 & 95 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 5 & 0 & 0 \\
    13 & 8 & 3994 & 29304 & 12 & 51 & 9422 & 40 & 98 & 87 & 88 & 48 & 11 & 1 \\
    14 & 4 & 4255 & 13786 & 34 & 124 & 9081 & 11 & 96 & 80 & 68 & 57 & 29 & 12 \\
    15 & 57 & 2874 & 43973 & 2 & 0 & 133 & 97 & 100 & 100 & 98 & 1 & 2 & 2 \\
    16 & 5 & 2788 & 12762 & 12 & 1130 & 15705 & 29 & 71 & 57 & 45 & 16 & 26 & 12 \\
    17 & 1 & 1695 & 3256 & 47 & 1542 & 23186 & 2 & 52 & 28 & 21 & 19 & 31 & 7 \\
    18 & 11 & 3000 & 22911 & 7 & 942 & 5286 & 61 & 76 & 79 & 63 & 2 & 13 & 16 \\
    19 & 4 & 1931 & 11220 & 46 & 681 & 27978 & 8 & 73 & 43 & 32 & 24 & 41 & 11 \\
    20 & 2 & 2313 & 9496 & 16 & 1025 & 16374 & 11 & 69 & 50 & 44 & 33 & 25 & 6 \\
    21 & 6 & 3001 & 17725 & 11 & 849 & 10174 & 35 & 78 & 70 & 59 & 24 & 19 & 11 \\
    22 & 11 & 3110 & 26569 & 26 & 176 & 14097 & 30 & 94 & 77 & 62 & 32 & 32 & 15 \\
    23 & 3 & 1544 & 8928 & 18 & 1660 & 18922 & 14 & 48 & 38 & 28 & 13 & 20 & 11 \\
    24 & 2 & 2493 & 10244 & 11 & 930 & 13499 & 15 & 73 & 56 & 61 & 46 & 12 & 6 \\
    25 & 4 & 4507 & 16480 & 3 & 111 & 3089 & 57 & 98 & 92 & 91 & 34 & 6 & 1 \\
    26 & 5 & 3887 & 19543 & 12 & 313 & 5750 & 29 & 92 & 85 & 78 & 48 & 15 & 7 \\
    27 & 7 & 3807 & 15196 & 18 & 346 & 12575 & 28 & 91 & 73 & 66 & 38 & 26 & 8 \\
    28 & 9 & 3475 & 24734 & 18 & 356 & 7398 & 33 & 90 & 83 & 59 & 26 & 31 & 24 \\
    29 & 14 & 4498 & 34149 & 4 & 2 & 1106 & 78 & 100 & 99 & 99 & 21 & 1 & 0 \\
    30 & 2 & 3553 & 9495 & 28 & 855 & 12517 & 7 & 80 & 63 & 56 & 49 & 25 & 8 \\
    31 & 2 & 2420 & 6294 & 33 & 874 & 13472 & 6 & 73 & 48 & 39 & 33 & 34 & 9 \\
    32 & 4 & 4560 & 12669 & 12 & 114 & 6343 & 25 & 97 & 84 & 87 & 62 & 10 & 3 \\
    33 & 8 & 3470 & 21527 & 84 & 146 & 27083 & 9 & 94 & 67 & 57 & 48 & 37 & 10 \\
    34 & 6 & 4432 & 18421 & 5 & 281 & 3504 & 55 & 94 & 90 & 81 & 26 & 13 & 9 \\
    35 & 5 & 3416 & 17312 & 23 & 184 & 16463 & 18 & 94 & 70 & 68 & 50 & 27 & 3 \\
    36 & 1 & 2031 & 4433 & 24 & 1224 & 18491 & 4 & 62 & 36 & 45 & 41 & 17 & 8 \\
    37 & 30 & 4804 & 56228 & 2 & 0 & 290 & 94 & 100 & 100 & 97 & 4 & 3 & 2 \\
    38 & 4 & 3260 & 17592 & 6 & 762 & 5336 & 40 & 81 & 79 & 62 & 22 & 19 & 17 \\
    39 & 2 & 3041 & 10377 & 20 & 609 & 15052 & 9 & 83 & 60 & 57 & 48 & 26 & 3 \\
    40 & 2 & 1749 & 6278 & 39 & 1064 & 28640 & 5 & 61 & 33 & 57 & 53 & 4 & 24 \\
    41 & 12 & 4085 & 26084 & 6 & 204 & 4524 & 67 & 95 & 90 & 81 & 14 & 14 & 9 \\
    42 & 3 & 2614 & 10498 & 24 & 919 & 11723 & 11 & 74 & 59 & 46 & 35 & 28 & 13 \\
    43 & 25 & 3453 & 41419 & 13 & 51 & 3935 & 66 & 98 & 94 & 83 & 17 & 15 & 11 \\
    44 & 6 & 3502 & 25113 & 10 & 191 & 7150 & 38 & 95 & 85 & 72 & 35 & 22 & 13 \\
    45 & 4 & 3099 & 12912 & 19 & 425 & 14178 & 17 & 87 & 65 & 61 & 44 & 26 & 4 \\
    46 & 8 & 4107 & 19800 & 18 & 111 & 6258 & 31 & 97 & 87 & 74 & 43 & 23 & 13 \\
    47 & 6 & 3037 & 21570 & 18 & 727 & 19776 & 25 & 80 & 65 & 52 & 27 & 28 & 13 \\
    48 & 14 & 2995 & 37882 & 10 & 732 & 8220 & 58 & 80 & 81 & 65 & 7 & 15 & 16 \\
    49 & 14 & 3035 & 30844 & 21 & 212 & 9652 & 40 & 93 & 83 & 61 & 21 & 32 & 22 \\
    50 & 8 & 4682 & 19595 & 11 & 75 & 3011 & 42 & 98 & 93 & 85 & 43 & 13 & 8 \\
    51 & 5 & 4705 & 15508 & 14 & 72 & 5187 & 26 & 98 & 89 & 82 & 56 & 16 & 7 \\
    52 & 5 & 2689 & 16291 & 21 & 653 & 15165 & 19 & 80 & 63 & 49 & 29 & 31 & 15 \\
    53 & 9 & 4293 & 24187 & 6 & 64 & 4828 & 60 & 98 & 91 & 90 & 30 & 9 & 2 \\
    54 & 2 & 2984 & 8316 & 24 & 457 & 20057 & 8 & 86 & 53 & 55 & 48 & 31 & 2 \\
    55 & 23 & 4592 & 36227 & 1 & 0 & 169 & 96 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 4 & 0 & 0 \\
    56 & 2 & 3017 & 7494 & 23 & 808 & 11079 & 8 & 78 & 58 & 58 & 50 & 21 & 1 \\
    57 & 14 & 4036 & 24331 & 23 & 7 & 6778 & 38 & 99 & 89 & 85 & 47 & 15 & 4 \\
    58 & 9 & 3886 & 29559 & 7 & 224 & 4243 & 56 & 94 & 91 & 72 & 16 & 23 & 19 \\
    59 & 3 & 3312 & 12149 & 13 & 699 & 13556 & 19 & 82 & 64 & 60 & 41 & 23 & 5 \\
    60 & 20 & 3865 & 26047 & 4 & 22 & 1164 & 83 & 99 & 97 & 92 & 9 & 7 & 5 \\
    61 & 4 & 3807 & 10305 & 11 & 223 & 7531 & 27 & 94 & 76 & 72 & 45 & 23 & 4 \\
    62 & 4 & 3375 & 9418 & 44 & 156 & 14695 & 8 & 94 & 63 & 55 & 47 & 39 & 8 \\
    63 & 18 & 3779 & 36773 & 6 & 58 & 2133 & 75 & 98 & 96 & 89 & 14 & 9 & 7 \\
    64 & 26 & 4228 & 39503 & 7 & 0 & 829 & 79 & 100 & 99 & 96 & 17 & 4 & 3 \\
    65 & 4 & 2889 & 11938 & 41 & 475 & 18420 & 9 & 85 & 58 & 42 & 34 & 42 & 16 \\
    66 & 4 & 2963 & 12567 & 28 & 337 & 15446 & 13 & 89 & 63 & 47 & 34 & 42 & 16 \\
    67 & 13 & 5727 & 42627 & 4 & 0 & 372 & 76 & 100 & 100 & 96 & 19 & 4 & 4 \\
    68 & 6 & 2871 & 16348 & 10 & 738 & 7918 & 38 & 79 & 73 & 55 & 17 & 25 & 18 \\
    69 & 2 & 1868 & 7427 & 35 & 1056 & 26696 & 5 & 63 & 37 & 33 & 27 & 30 & 4 \\
    70 & 17 & 3604 & 29458 & 18 & 42 & 6866 & 49 & 98 & 89 & 69 & 21 & 29 & 20 \\
    71 & 3 & 5095 & 11407 & 7 & 16 & 3606 & 30 & 100 & 91 & 86 & 56 & 13 & 4 \\
    72 & 10 & 3660 & 25456 & 29 & 164 & 7578 & 26 & 95 & 86 & 71 & 45 & 24 & 14 \\
    73 & 1 & 1286 & 2800 & 39 & 1509 & 31159 & 3 & 45 & 21 & 17 & 15 & 28 & 4 \\
    74 & 31 & 3678 & 38338 & 2 & 6 & 966 & 94 & 100 & 99 & 94 & 0 & 6 & 5 \\
    75 & 37 & 3475 & 35754 & 1 & 0 & 38 & 97 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\
    76 & 4 & 3633 & 13414 & 15 & 281 & 9752 & 21 & 92 & 75 & 73 & 52 & 20 & 2 \\
    77 & 4 & 4027 & 14324 & 10 & 528 & 7550 & 29 & 88 & 78 & 63 & 35 & 25 & 15 \\
    78 & 6 & 4050 & 18021 & 13 & 59 & 7520 & 32 & 98 & 85 & 72 & 40 & 26 & 13 \\
    79 & 4 & 2684 & 10807 & 23 & 485 & 12193 & 15 & 84 & 61 & 44 & 30 & 40 & 17 \\
    80 & 24 & 3977 & 44696 & 12 & 13 & 4172 & 67 & 99 & 95 & 89 & 23 & 10 & 6 \\
    81 & 2 & 1126 & 5397 & 28 & 2161 & 24036 & 7 & 34 & 25 & 21 & 14 & 13 & 4 \\
    82 & 25 & 3516 & 27515 & 11 & 31 & 1966 & 69 & 99 & 96 & 85 & 16 & 14 & 11 \\
    83 & 10 & 4834 & 41025 & 5 & 19 & 3540 & 67 & 100 & 96 & 90 & 23 & 10 & 7 \\
    84 & 29 & 5083 & 57971 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    85 & 28 & 4293 & 42918 & 1 & 0 & 181 & 97 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\
    86 & 6 & 4224 & 16577 & 7 & 111 & 4214 & 46 & 97 & 89 & 76 & 29 & 22 & 13 \\
    87 & 11 & 3689 & 19672 & 25 & 102 & 10972 & 31 & 97 & 79 & 70 & 39 & 27 & 10 \\
    88 & 1 & 1496 & 3735 & 28 & 1647 & 29735 & 3 & 47 & 25 & 30 & 27 & 17 & 5 \\
    89 & 5 & 4083 & 17870 & 7 & 114 & 4593 & 42 & 97 & 89 & 85 & 43 & 12 & 4 \\
    90 & 20 & 3711 & 32478 & 14 & 40 & 3570 & 59 & 99 & 94 & 87 & 28 & 12 & 7 \\
    91 & 6 & 3905 & 20334 & 21 & 114 & 13450 & 22 & 97 & 78 & 71 & 49 & 26 & 7 \\
    92 & 2 & 2024 & 7164 & 45 & 1157 & 26033 & 4 & 63 & 38 & 28 & 24 & 35 & 10 \\
    93 & 6 & 4331 & 19434 & 24 & 54 & 8137 & 20 & 98 & 85 & 81 & 61 & 18 & 5 \\
    94 & 4 & 3617 & 19607 & 11 & 376 & 9633 & 27 & 90 & 78 & 68 & 41 & 22 & 10 \\
    95 & 5 & 3955 & 18959 & 13 & 128 & 9825 & 28 & 97 & 81 & 80 & 52 & 16 & 1 \\
    96 & 20 & 4098 & 43062 & 7 & 23 & 3181 & 74 & 99 & 96 & 90 & 16 & 9 & 6 \\
    97 & 1 & 1707 & 4099 & 25 & 1279 & 18039 & 4 & 57 & 33 & 34 & 30 & 22 & 2 \\
    98 & 25 & 3694 & 37010 & 11 & 36 & 2635 & 69 & 99 & 96 & 83 & 13 & 16 & 13 \\
    99 & 2 & 2012 & 7367 & 23 & 1217 & 21431 & 8 & 62 & 40 & 32 & 24 & 30 & 8 \\
    100 & 5 & 3745 & 16101 & 7 & 356 & 5564 & 42 & 91 & 83 & 72 & 31 & 19 & 10 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{longtable}
  \endgroup
  \captionof{table}{Caption}
\end{document}
```

[image: isolate caption]

Comment: I never thought of using another package. I guess that'll work. The vertical space between the table and the caption is bigger that expected/wanted but I assume I'll be able to fix that as well when I'll read the `caption` documentation.